# A mystery of accessing variables

Tags: pine-script

I clearly am a noob so I am grateful if anyone could explain why this labels numbers?

```
//@version=4
study(title="Test", shorttitle="Test", overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)

ma = sma(close,50)
label.new(bar_index, close,tostring(ma, "#.##"), yloc = yloc.belowbar, color = color.red, textcolor = color.black, style = label.style_none)

plot(na)
```

While this one labels **NaN**

```
//@version=4
study(title="Test", shorttitle="Test", overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)

ma = sma(close,50)
var txtt=tostring(ma, "#.##")
label.new(bar_index, close,txtt, yloc = yloc.belowbar, color = color.red, textcolor = color.black, style = label.style_none)

plot(na)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `txtt` as `var`.
A `var` is only initialized once at the start of a script, and keeps its value throughout the script.
Remove the `var` from `txtt` and it should work fine.

```
txtt = tostring(ma, "#.##")
```

Or you could do

```
var string txtt = na
txtt := tostring(ma, "#.##")
```

Both should work.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, if I don't use `var` it will be a `series`, right?

Comment: It will always be a series, regardless of the use of var.